# Вывод строки по периметру квадрата

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Пока набросал код, который делает лишь половину работы, а именно имя пишется вправо и вниз:

```
name = str(input("Введите имя, которое хотите получить квадратиком "))
print(name)
for letter in name:
    if letter > name[0]:
        print(letter)
```

Я не могу понять, как реверсивно написать имя с отступами (получается от длины слова нужно отнять 2 (первая и последняя буква) это будет строчка квадрата которая идёт вниз с другой стороны) и как реверсивно написать нижнюю строчку квадрата, при этом не делая в коде отступ на новую строчку(иначе квадрата, разумеется, не будет)

```
В а с я
а     с
с     а
я с а В
```

Comment: Что значит "квадратиком"?

Comment: Не могу написать в комментарии: представьте просто напечатанное слово, а потом оно же, только уже идёт по букве в строчке вниз - это мы получили одно слово, которое написанно слева направо и сверху вниз. Я хочу, чтобы это же слово было написано ещё и сверху вниз и справа налево, чтобы выглядело как какой-то "квадрат" из слова. Надеюсь понятно

Comment: @Никита Смирнов Посмотрите - я правильно добавил? Если нет, сами отредактируйте, чтобы было наглядно

Comment: Спасибо! Всё верно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def square_print(s):
    print(*s)
    _cut = s[1:-1]
    for direct, reverse in zip(_cut, reversed(_cut)):
        print(f'{direct}{reverse:>{len(s) * 2 - 2}}')
    print(*reversed(s))
    

s = "AnyString"
square_print(s)
```

Краткое пояснение:

Первая строка выводится не как объект строки, а как коллекция, поэтому, по-умолчанию, добавляется пробел-разделитель.

Дальше создается копия-подстрока, содержащая исходную без первого и последнего символа. По этой подстроке проходим прямым и обратным итератором. При печати содержимого обратного итератора форматируем ширину поля на величину длины исходной строки умноженной на 2 (т.к. для каждого исходного символа добавили пробел), и минус 2 символа (первый и последний).

Последняя строка выводится аналогично первой, но в инверсном порядке.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Попытаюсь понять, как это сделано :)

Comment: Про коллекцию не знал, Спасибо)

Comment: Догнал! Про f не знал, думал, через формат делается такое. Ну про коллекции тем более не знал) Красивый код получился

Answer (score 3):

Вот вам в копилку с использованием `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

def sqrPrint(a: str):
    arr = np.full([len(a), len(a)], " ")
    for i in (arr, np.rot90(arr,2)):
        i[0,:], i.T[0] = list(a), list(a)
    [print(' '.join(x)) for x in arr]

sqrPrint("Абырвалг")
```

Ну и результат:

```
А б ы р в а л г
б             л
ы             а
р             в
в             р
а             ы
л             б
г л а в р ы б А
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот как то так)

```
def square_print(name):
    back_name = name[::-1]
    print(*name)
    for i in range(len(name[1:]) - 1):
        print(name[1:][i], ((len(name) * 2) - 5) * " ", back_name[1:][i])
    print(*back_name)
    
square_print('Trofimov')
```

я думаю принцип понятен, только нужно поработать с дополнительными пробелами.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!